# passing datetime parameters in C#

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I have the following code with is part of an overall code to Add customer details into a Windows Form and transfer the data to SQL. I am only new to coding and I am not sure how to fix the following error:

```
  Customers customer = new Customers(GlobalVariables.selectedCustomerID,
                           lbCategoryID.Item[cbCategory.SelectedIndex].ToString(),
                           txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, cbGender.Text,
                           txtAddress.Text,
                           txtSuburb.Text, cbState.Text,
                           int.Parse(txtPostcode.Text).ToString()), dtpBirthdate.Value);
```

I get a red line under "Value" - states "; expected"

and also Customers (after new) - states "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter "birthdate" of Customers.Customers (int, int, string, string, string, string, string, string, int, DateTime)'."

I am not sure what I need to do to fix this issue. The Birthdate is in DateTime format within a Customer Class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have too many brackets...

Comment: int.Parse(txtPostcode.Text).ToString(), dtpBirthdate.Value); there is an extra )

Comment: extra bracket after  int.Parse(txtPostcode.Text).ToString() needs to be removed

Comment: Question: Why are you parsing `string` to `int` then converting it to `string` again? `int.Parse(txtPostcode.Text).ToString()`

Comment: @SeM Let's handle one error after the other, ok? ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are sending a string in the second parameter `lbCategoryID.Item[cbCategory.SelectedIndex].ToString(),` and by the error message you should be sending integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Customers customer = new Customers(GlobalVariables.selectedCustomerID,           lbCategoryID.Item[cbCategory.SelectedIndex],                       txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, cbGender.Text,                  txtAddress.Text, txtSuburb.Text, cbState.Text, int.Parse(txtPostcode.Text), dtpBirthdate.Value);
```

Have removed the extra .ToString() for int.Parse(txtPostcode.Text) and lbCategoryID.Item[cbCategory.SelectedIndex];

Answer (score 0):

As for the specific error: Remove the stray bracket after `int.Parse(txtPostcode.Text).ToString())`. The compiler correctly thinks that the statement should end here, but is then missing a semicolon.

After that you're going to have to handle all your other errors: 
Obviously, the constructor requires two `int`s in the first two parameters. You're not providing two `int`s, but the second parameter is a `string`.

Also, you're not providing an `int` for the post code.

So all in all your parameters do not match the required types at all.